# Issue with bot responding multiple times to one command discord.py

Tags: python, python-3.x, discord, discord.py

I only have one console open, I think this is because of the on_message because once I remove those it only responds once like it should. I am using await self.client.process_commands(message) after so really not sure why it would repeat. Please let me know if you have any suggestions.

Comment: Please include your code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I thenk you are using `Cog` and `Cog.listener()`.

`event` and `listener` in `discord.py` is 2 different decorator. for example `listeners` called in `events`.

remove this line:

```py
await self.client.process_commands(message)
```

Comment: How are you able to know those things with the little of context he provided?

Comment: sorry I do not know the answer to this question. but I think `on_command` event and `Command.before_invoke` are helpful for you.